# Forwarding touches from SwiftUI View with transparent background to UIKit view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uihostingcontroller

I have a large SwiftUI view that contains a bottom menu and some small UI components above it. I want to overlay this view on top of an existing `UIViewController` instance and therefore using a `UIHostingController`.

The problem I'm having is that, the transparent regions of my SwiftUI view do not forward the touches despite the background of both the SwiftUI view and the view of the `UIHostingController` being transparent.

Since I can't replace the view subclass used by the `UIHostingController`, I can't mess with its hit testing mechanism to make it forward the touches manually.

Is there a way to accomplish this? It seems to be impossible right now.